# Enforce AllowedPattern for parameter of type CommaDelimitedList in Cloudformation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to enforce an allowed pattern with regex on my parameter, but when I try to build my stack, I get the following error message:

> Template validation error: Template error: Parameter 'myParam' AllowedPattern must be on a parameter of type String

This is my Parameter definition:

```
"myParam": {
   "Description": "this is my param",
   "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
   "AllowedPattern": "\\+[0-9\\-\\ ]+",
   "MinLength": "1"
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can't do regex on CommaDelimitedList. Regex can only be applied on strings.

CommaDelimitedList – An array of literal strings that are separated by commas

Comment: So there's currently no way to have a parameter that is a list of strings, each of which must match a particular pattern?

Comment: @MarkReed regex is only allowed for strings, the commadelilist is technically an array, so aws doesnt allow it

Comment: This answer seems out of date. The [latest documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) for `AllowedPattern` says, "When applied to a parameter of type `CommaDelimitedList,` the pattern must match each value in the list."

Answer (score 3):

AllowedPattern (and AllowedValues) for CommaDelimitedLists are now supported in CloudFormation parameters. If you apply an AllowedPattern or AllowedValues on a CommaDelimitedList, the constraint is checked for each item in the list. See the documentation here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html