# Unable to use AllowedPattern for CloudFormation CommaDelimitedList parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

Note that this question is *not* the same as [Enforce AllowedPattern for parameter of type CommaDelimitedList in Cloudformation script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32339584), because that question was written before `AllowedPattern` was supported for `CommaDelimitedList`, and thus the error message shown is different and the accepted answer is out of no longer accurate.

I have an AWS CloudFormation template with the following parameter:

```yaml
  Profiles:
    Description: The comma-separated list of active profiles, such as "dev,test".
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: ""
    AllowedPattern: '\w+'
    ConstraintDescription: Active profile identifiers must only use word characters, separated by commas.
```

The [latest documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) for `AllowedPattern` says:

> When applied to a parameter of type `CommaDelimitedList`, the pattern must match each value in the list.

I try to invoke `aws cloudformation deploy …` passing the `Profiles` parameter:

```bash
aws cloudformation deploy … --parameter-overrides … Profiles=dev,test
```

This doesn't work either:

```bash
aws cloudformation deploy … --parameter-overrides … Profiles="dev,test"
```

In fact even this doesn't work!

```bash
aws cloudformation deploy … --parameter-overrides … Profiles=dev
```

The AWS CLI tells me:

> `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Parameter Profiles failed to satisfy constraint: Active profile identifiers must only use word characters, separated by commas.`

If I remove `AllowedPattern`, it works:

```yaml
  Profiles:
    Description: The comma-separated list of active profiles, such as "dev,test".
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: ""
    # AllowedPattern: '\w+'
    ConstraintDescription: Active profile identifiers must only use word characters, separated by commas.
```

If I switch to PowerShell and try this, it fails as well:

```
aws cloudformation deploy … --parameter-overrides … Profiles=dev,test
```

This fails, too, in PowerShell:

```
aws cloudformation deploy … --parameter-overrides … 'Profiles=dev'
```

And this fails, too, in PowerShell:

```
aws cloudformation deploy … --parameter-overrides '… Profiles=dev'
```

I'm beginning to think that `AllowedPattern` is simply broken with `CommaDelimitedList` in CloudFormation when called from the CLI.

Comment: Try quoting both the key and the value: `aws cloudformation deploy … --parameter-overrides … "Profiles=dev,test"`

Comment: Nope, `aws cloudformation deploy … --parameter-overrides … "Profiles=dev,test"` gives me exactly the same thing. Have you tried it?

Comment: What shell are you using? see https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3274#issuecomment-382887442

Comment: I have tried it both with WSL Ubuntu Bash and Windows Git Bash. Show me any combination for Bash that will work.

Comment: Of course you don't have to. "Show me any combination …" in the context means "I'll take anything that works". Thank you for your attempts so far.

Comment: This is simply a bug. I filed ticket [aws-cli Issue #7750](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/7750), and it was acknowledged by someone but apparently not given sufficient priority.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed CloudFormation simply seems to be broken with `AllowedPattern` combined with `CommaDelimitedList`. I opened [AllowedPattern broken with CommaDelimitedList parameter #7750](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/7750) half a year ago, still without a fix.